# rails 7 and stripe: how can i retrieve metadata in my webhooks controller from the payment_intent.succeeded object in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

You can see in the line for Payment.create I have a mix of syntax's where the syntax used for email value includes curly braces I don't how I got that I must have copied it I left it like that for my question which is how do I get the metadata from the returned event.data.object in my webhooks controller so that Payment.create will create a new record with the post_id ?

checkouts_controller:

```
  def create
      session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [
          price_data: {
            product: 'prod_Miva1sJtJ29QeC',
            unit_amount: 500,
            currency: 'usd',
          },
          quantity: 1,
        ],
        metadata: {user_id: current_user.id, post_id: params[:post_id]},
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: root_url(success: true),
        cancel_url: root_url,
      })
```

webhooks_controller:

```
  when 'payment_intent.succeeded'
    session=event.data.object.payment_intent
    post_id = session.metadata['post_id']
    Payment.create(post_id: session.metadata["post_id"], time_stamp: Time.now.to_datetime.utc, email: "${session.email}")
    render json: { message: 'success' }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `metadata` created on Checkout Session object in your request doesn't get populated into Payment Intent object, the event that you described.

To have metadata shown at the Payment Intent, [`payment_intent_data.metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) should also be set in the request when creating a Checkout Session. For example,

```
session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
  line_items: [{
    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',
      product_data: {
        name: 'T-shirt',
      },
      unit_amount: 2000,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  metadata: {
    user_id: 'user_123', 
    post_id: 'post_id_123'
  },
  payment_intent_data: {
    user_id: 'user_123',
    post_id: 'post_id_123',
  }
})
```

Comment: I already found that out but thanks that's awesome that you showed me I can add payment_intent_data to the Checkout::Session object It seems I don't need to use payment_intent as long as I receive a checkout.session.completed webhook that should mean payment's been made successfully I suppose payment_intent is for other scenarios